# how to enter an array values in table to fill in no of rows in 1 column?

Tags: javascript, html

i want in table seven header are there example:numbers,assending order,decending order,max values,min values,sum of all values,avg values...
an array values i had taken random values....and it should be entered in no of rows and only in 1 column...

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table" border="2" style="border:12px solid brown">
        <tr>
            <th>numbers</th>
            <th>assending order</th>
            <th>decenting order</th>
            <th>max value</th>
            <th>minimum value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td></td>
        </tr>
<p id="all">sd</p>
    </table>
    <script>
        var array=[["1"],["5"],["10"],["6"],["3"],["17"],["19"],["24"],["7"],["8"],["11"],
        ["13"],["15"],["15"],["12"],["14"],["16"],["18"],["21"],["20"]],

     table=document.getElementById("table")

        for(i=1;i<array.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<table.rows[i].cells[0].length;j++){
                table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=array[i][j];
console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=array[i][j])
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Get the reference of the table through it's `id` value as `document.getElementById("table")`
2. set the value of `array` which you want to fill in the table. Also set the number of columns value in a variable, say `columns` so that you can loop over each column and fill the values for each row in each column.
3. Create a new row `table.insertRow(i+1);` below each created row
4. Create columns for each row `row.insertCell(j);`
5. Insert the value in each column from the array `cells[j].innerHTML=array[i][j];`

```js
var array=[["1"],["5"],["10"],["6"],["3"],["17"],["19"],["24"],["7"],["8"],["11"],
["13"],["15"],["15"],["12"],["14"],["16"],["18"],["21"],["20"]];

var table = document.getElementById("table");
var columns = 5;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
  var cells = [];
  for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
    cells[j] = row.insertCell(j);
    if(array[i][j]){
      cells[j].innerHTML=array[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="2" style="border:12px solid brown">
  <tr>
      <th>numbers</th>
      <th>assending order</th>
      <th>decenting order</th>
      <th>max value</th>
      <th>minimum value</th>
  </tr>
<p id="all">Table</p>
</table>
```

Comment: tq ankit agarwal

Comment: @abhineshghugloth you can vote up and tick mark it to green if it was really helpful o you